# Command works in command line but gives 'no such file or directory' in bash script

Tags: bash, cygwin

Like the tags say, this is in Cygwin.

I have a command line program that I can run from the Cygwin console:

```
./optAlg.exe data/5Node/1.dat 500 2>&1 > output/1.out
```

I wrote the following bash script to put it in a loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for inputFile in data/5Node/*.dat
do
  outputFile=${inputFile##*/} #strip output name from input name
  outputFile=${outputFile%.*} #strip output name input file
  outputFile+=".out"
  "./optAlg.exe $inputFile 500 2>&1 > output/$outputFile"
done
```

When I run the bash script, for every iteration of the for loop I get 'No such file or directory', e.g.,

```
./batchOpt.sh: line 8: ./optAlg.exe data/5Node/1.dat 500 2>&1 > output/1.out: No such file or directory
```

What's happening here? What I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is the question answered? Yes? Accept and answer please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes around line 8.
Like this:

```
./optAlg.exe "$inputFile" 500 2>&1 > "output/$outputFile"
```

By placing quotes around the whole line you tell bash to execute a command which is called exactly `./optAlg.exe $inputFile 500 2>&1 > output/$outputFile` and of course there is no such command. In reality you want to run `./optAlg.exe` with parameters. Do not forget to place quotes around the variables because otherwise filenames that have whitespace characters are going to be passed as several arguments.
Please [read about arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments).
And you can read about [common pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) as well.